# How to send information to server from django

Tags: html, django, openai-api

My problem is that I have a text field that I want to have, when submitted, sent information to the django server. First am trying to accomplish this as you can see so I haven't built anything more to do this, but my idea is that on clicking the button, I append a value on a list through which I use this.

```
{ % for value in list %}
  { % value % }
{ % endfor % }
```

I am tryingg, in summary to make this a working ChatGPT application that can successfully send data. The source code is avalible at https://gist.github.com/s0urce-c0de/fce620fdb61c0b9d30e1ac5361cac039.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, you committed only a zip file to GitHub. How can we help wothout downloading and unzipping it? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML and the web in general you have requests. Requests are, as the name implies, requesting something, in this case to a server. The way to do this is through a URL. There are also types of requests, but the most basic one is GET.
In this case, I don't know what is your intent with the information you want to send, but for simplicity, I'll assume GET is the right thing to do here.

First, you need a `<form>`. A form is an HTML element that allows you to do these requests. It is very simple to use. In your case, you are saying you need a text field, so it will be something like this:

```
<form action="/your-url" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="text" id="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This way, you'll make a request to `http://localhost/your-url` and will have a text input with a name of "text"

The way to acces this in the views is:

```py
def my_view(request):
  # Get text from request
  text = request.GET.get("text")

  # Whatever you want to do with the text
  ...
```

Note that in `urls.py` you'll have to link the url with the view.